# Spring data JPA native query skip locked

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to execute a `SKIP LOCKED` query on Oracle using Spring Data JPA, so I tried the following:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID=?1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED", nativeQuery = true)
User findOne(UUID id);
```

I tried the above and found that the generated query contains `FOR UPDATE`, but not `SKIP LOCKED` (below is the generated query from logs):

```
select ent0_.column1 as name, ent0_.CREATED_DATE as CREATED_2_33_0_ from TABLE_NAME alias_name where ent0_.column1=? for update
```

If I remove `@Lock` from the query method, the generated query does not even have `FOR UPDATE`.

Please suggest how I can generate a query with `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`, as required.

Comment: As you have found, `FOR UPDATE` is being added by `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` and not your native query. Since JPA is a database-agnostic specification, this is unfortunately as far as you can go with JPA, because, `SKIP LOCKED` is a Oracle-specific feature. If it is essential for you to use database-specific features, you will have to write a custom repository implementation that executes raw SQL over an `EntityManager` directly.

Answer (score 5):

You can assing `-2` to timeout value so that 'skip locked' will be used whenever possible.

> PESSIMISTIC_WRITE with a javax.persistence.lock.timeout setting of -2
>
> UPGRADE_SKIPLOCKED
>
> The lock acquisition request skips the already locked rows. It uses a
>   SELECT …​ FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED in Oracle and PostgreSQL 9.5, or
>   SELECT …​ with (rowlock, updlock, readpast) in SQL Server.

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    /**
     * The lock acquisition request skips the already locked rows.
     * It uses a SELECT …​ FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED in Oracle and PostgreSQL 9.5,
     * or SELECT …​ with (rowlock, updlock, readpast) in SQL Server.
     */
    String UPGRADE_SKIPLOCKED = "-2";

    @Lock(value = LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) // adds 'FOR UPDATE' statement
    @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = UPGRADE_SKIPLOCKED)})
    MyEntity findFirstByStatus(String status);

}
```

By doing like this, the select query will have `select ... for update skip locked`

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/chapters/locking/Locking.html

Answer (score 1):

Add:

> @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value
>   ="-2")})