# Allocation of data to Concurrent users

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, database-design, concurrency

In our application we use microservices architecture. One of the microservice is allocation microservice.
This allocation microservice functionality is to assign 100 different records to the user who has logged in our application, from Postgres DB which has a total records of 1 million in one of the table.

Currently we are using spring boot and we are handling it using Optimistic locking mechanism. For even, When around than 100 concurrent users are using the application, the performance of the application is drastically slow, and the allocation microservice takes about more than 2 minutes to allocate the data to users. Once the data is allocated, we are storing the data in redis.

(Its a DB update, we change the status from "assigned" to "allocated" and also update the "assignedTo" field to the particular user. The use case is, no two same records should be allocated to the same user, to avoid this we are using "Optimistic lock" and the performance of the System is very slow in this case. Any other solutions to improve the performance ?)

Any other solution to improve the performance apart from Optimistic locking?

Comment: What do you mean by "assign records to the user"? Is it DB update or you load them to memory? Please, add the code of this block. It is not clear yet.

Comment: Its a DB update, we change the status from "assigned" to "allocated" and also update the "allocatedto" field to the particular user.  The use case is, no two same records should be allocated to the same user, to avoid this we are using "Optimistic lock" and the performance of the System is very slow in this case. Any other solutions to improve the performance ?

Comment: Do you update records one by one or as a batch? Do you allocate the same records to different users?

Comment: We should not allocate the same records to different user. We update the one by one .. a set of 100 records to one user.

Answer (score 0):

Allocation of task to users is a job queue pattern.

It's easy to make it wrong or to make it very slow for concurrent users in a database.
But it is quite common with known solutions, using pessimistic locks on database rows for the duration of database transaction, for example with [spring-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208705/spring-data-jpa-native-query-skip-locked/55280174#55280174) in spring-boot or with [native sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058253/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-skip-locked-rows-postgresql).

If you select and lock many rows and not one by one (limit 1) in each transaction, you may add an order by on the primary key to avoid potential deadlocks.